# Is using Default​Network​Credentials a security hole?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, security

In my company we have a SharePoint server and an Active Directory domain. If I want to get any information from the SharePoint server, I have to send over some credentials like this:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Method = "GET";
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials; // <-- credentials
var response = request.GetResponse();
```

This works fine and is no problem because I *trust* the SharePoint server.

But I was wondering: **Is it a security problem to send `DefaultNetworkCredentials` to an untrusted server?** Can an untrusted server use these credentials to impersonate me/the user? Can it extract my password from these credentials?

I'm guessing/hoping these credentials don't just contain the (plain-text) Windows password. However, the [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.net.credentialcache.defaultnetworkcredentials?view=netframework-4.7) for `DefaultNetworkCredentials` states:

> The credentials returned by DefaultNetworkCredentials represents the authentication credentials for the current security context in which the application is running. For a client-side application, these are usually **the Windows credentials (user name, password, and domain)** of the user running the application.

There's also this remark (in the same MSDN document):

> The credentials returned by the DefaultNetworkCredentials property is applicable **only for NTLM, negotiate, and Kerberos-based authentication**.

I'm guessing that means that `DefaultNetworkCredentials` is safe to use - but I like to have some confirmation on that; because I don't know what "NTLM, negotiate, and Kerberos-based authentication" really means - except that they're (probably) some kind of authentication mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

Kerberos auth is the safest authentication method to use in this scenario. NTLM is less secure and Negotiate lets the client and server use Kerberos if both of them support it - if not they fallback to NTLM. However, clear text credentials in the form of a password are not send over the network. The same mechanism is used when accessing your SharePoint site using Internet Explorer, which also does not send the password but uses your default network credentials.
As long as your server is configured to use windows authentication with these providers (NTLM, Negotiate, Kerberos) and NOT basic or forms authentication there will be no security issue.

You may want to refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480475.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 for details on IIS Authentication and its methods.